# Topic: Ripper X & Asunder CD Ripper

Tags: 20.04, internet, connection, cddb

I happen to be an old fuddy duddy who still rips CD's (Thanks for not laughing out loud), when I went from Ubuntu 19. something to Ubuntu 20.04 both Ripper X and Asunder are unable to connect to the CD database and download any pertinent information. As best as I can determine none of the config settings are any different. I'm pretty sure the problem does not reside in the config settings.  Internet connection works for every other program the way it should.  Any suggestions on how I can get things back to normal? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

This happened because of FreeDB CDDB [downing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedb):

> freedb.org and its services was scheduled to be shut down on March 31 of 2020. As of May 28, 2020 the site was still operational.
> On the 13th of June 2020 it was observed that the URL used for lookups, freedb.freedb.org, no longer resolved to a host name and as a result the service no longer appears to operate.

You have to try switching Asunder to [GNUDB](http://www.gnudb.org):

1. Open Asunder
2. Select *Preferences*
3. Navigate to *Advanced* tab
4. In *CDDB* area change server from `freedb.freedb.org` to `gnudb.gnudb.org`
5. Retry *CDDB Lookup* with Audio CD inserted

For RipperX do the following to switch it to other CDDB site:

1. Open RipperX
2. Click *Config*
3. Navigate to *CDDB* tab
4. In *CDDB Configuration* are change *URL* from `freedb.freedb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi` to `freedb.dbpoweramp.com/~cddb/cddb.cgi`
5. Retry CDDB retrieval with Audio CD inserted.

I have checked both above servers with CD disc dated 1994.

---

Notes: there is 3rd alternative with port 80 - `http://us.cddb.com/~cddb/cddb.cgi`.

Comment: Just a note as of May 2021 gnudb.gnudb.org works over port `8880`, which I believe used to be `8080` but changed at some point.

Comment: As of February 2022 the ripperX alternative site is working just fine

Answer (score 1):

For asunder look in your home directory for a hidden `.config` folder.
Open that and edit the file `asunder` with a text editor to replace "cddb" with "gnudb.gnudb.org".

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me with asunder is to also specify the proxy for gnudb as `proxy.gnudb.org` on port 3128.