# RipperX 2.80 on 20.04 not creating output files

Tags: 20.04, mp3, cd-ripping

installed RipperX 2.80 on Ubuntu 20.04 for ripping CDs to MP3. No problems with installation.

Runs OK, but I must be missing a configuration switch somewhere. It happily picks up the media detail from gnudb.gnudb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi, creates a folder named for the artist, a subfolder named for the album, rips every track, but doesn't create any actual MP3 files. The album folder remains empty.

Initially, it created a single small .m3u playlist file (I have no idea what this is for), but I've switched that function off. There doesn't appear to be any equivalent function that switches on MP3 file creation.

I'm sure the answer is embarrassingly obvious, but RipperX has no Help or online manual that I can find. There's (at least) one helpful YouTube recording out there, but frustratingly, it doesn't end by showing the resulting MP3 files.

All suggestions gratefully received.

Cheers

John M

Comment: Do you know for sure this app runs on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: This software dates back to 2014-2015 most likely way to old to run on 20.04

Comment: Fair comment; I don't know.  What's your recommendation for an alternative?

Comment: But I did find this on AskUbuntu:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255906/topic-ripper-x-asunder-cd-ripper

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few answers.

First, RipperX 2.80 works absolutely fine on Ubuntu 20.04.

Second, it only creates MP3 files if you first install the LAME encoder. Whatever that means. I followed the instructions in this link: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/lame
and it installed first time without a problem.

It's not absolutely perfect (the time remaining is a bit shonky), but if you set the CDDB URL to:
gnudb.gnudb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi
Proxy server:  proxy.gnudb.org  and Proxy Port:  3128
it seems to do the job.

Thank you for the contributions,

Cheers,

John